Vitest Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')
Starting to build out a test suite and hit another bug in the process. I've written the first test that checks successful rendering of a UI component (components from ui directory are from ShadCn):
// NavBar.test.tsx
import { screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { describe, expect, test } from "vitest";

import { render } from "~/utils/test-utils";
import { NavBar } from "./NavBar";

describe("<NavBar />", () => {
    test("renders without errors", () => {
        render(<NavBar />);
        expect(screen.getByText("Free Agents")).toBeTruthy();
    });
});

// NavBar.tsx
"use client";

import { menuItems, NavMenuGroup, ProfileButton } from "./components";
import {
    NavigationMenu,
    NavigationMenuList,
} from "../ui";

export const NavBar = () => (
    <NavigationMenu>
        <NavigationMenuList className="flex justify-between p-4 w-full">
            <div className="flex space-x-10">
                {menuItems.map((groupItem, index) => (
                    <NavMenuGroup
                        groupItem={groupItem}
                        key={index} />
                ))}
                <ProfileButton />
            </div>
        </NavigationMenuList>
    </NavigationMenu>
);

We're using Clerk for auth so instead of importing a provider everywhere I have a wrapper for the render method.
// test-utils.tsx
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
const Clerk = require("@clerk/nextjs");
import { render, RenderOptions } from "@testing-library/react";
import { AppRouterContext, type AppRouterInstance } from "next/dist/shared/lib/app-router-context.shared-runtime";
import React, { FC, ReactElement, ReactNode } from "react";

import { TRPCReactProvider } from "~/trpc/react";

const { ClerkProvider } = Clerk;

const AllTheProviders: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => (
    <AppRouterContext.Provider value={{} as AppRouterInstance}>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <ClerkProvider>
                <TRPCReactProvider>
                    {children}
                </TRPCReactProvider>
            </ClerkProvider>
        </React.StrictMode>
    </AppRouterContext.Provider>
);

const customRender = (
    ui: ReactElement,
    options?: Omit<RenderOptions, "wrapper">,
) => render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options });

export * from "@testing-library/react";
export { customRender as render };

When I run this test I get an error I'm having trouble tracing:
I tried commenting out the Clerk dependent component thinking that was it but no. I made sure the test runner was properly configured by running an unfailable test (expect true to be truthy) and it passed.
Anytime I pass any component it I get this error.

Did you ever figure this out?
